# Select User Having Maximum Rating

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1

I have a table which stores the rating given by the user.

eg:

```
UserId  Rating
 3            1  
 3            2
 1            1
 1            2
 1            3
 1            4
 2            1
 2            23
 2            4
```

I need to retrieve the 10 users who have rated the maximum number of times.

eg:

```
 1 rated 4 times
 2 rated 3 times
 3 rated 2 times...
```

Any idea how to write a query using mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to group by userID, count the grouped rows, and order by the count in descending order, then you limit the query to 10 rows:

```
SELECT userID, count(*) times
FROM users
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY times DESC
LIMIT 10
```

If you need the output exactly as shown above, try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', userID, 'rated', count(*), 'times')
FROM users
GROUP BY userID
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
LIMIT 10
```

See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4b228/3).